# how number of replicas is aligned with crush rule in a ceph cluster

Tags: linux, replication, ceph

I have some difficulties to understand whether the `crush rule` is aligned with the number of replicas. So, imagine I create a crush rule named `replicate_in_2_racks` as follows:

```
ceph osd crush rule create-simple replicate_in_2_racks default rack
```

which as the name suggests, that is expected to be replicated across 2 racks in the crush map (the nodes/hosts of the our cluster is equally distributed in two racks, as set in the crush map). Then I create a pool called `pool01fordata`, as:

```
ceph osd create pool ceph osd pool create pool01fordata replicated replicate_in_2_racks
```

Until here, I'd have expected the number of replicas to be automatically set to `2`, as the crush rule `replicate_in_2_racks` was passed, but that is not the case, I still had to set the number of replicas as:

```
ceph osd pool set pool01fordata size 2
```

So, why if I have two racks in a crush map, and a pool is created with the corresponding rule, I still have to set the pool size (number of replicas)?

does it mean that if have the crush rule: `replicate_in_2_racks` I can set the number of replicas different to 2, like: `ceph osd pool set pool01fordata size 3` (which would not make sense to me)

Answer (score 0):

Because these settings are not directly related. One sets the number of replicas, one sets rules how replicas should be placed.

If you set the number of replicas to 3 (or higher) the rule will make sure that at least one replica is in a different rack than other replicas. The third will be placed wherever ceph thinks is suitable.

If you add another crush rule, for example, based on hosts, this would also be considered. For two it wouldn't matter, with 3 replicas the rack rule would make sure that the replicas are placed in different racks, while the hosts rule would make sure that on the rack where two replicas are placed, they will not be placed in the same host.

Remember that you can organize your disks in a tree of you own choosing, it can contain hosts, racks, rooms, buildings, continents, whatever. And you can set up crush rules anyway you want to distribute the replicas.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That clarifies things.